# SSRS: expression in a calculated field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, calculated-field, ssrs-expression

I am trying to write an expression in a calculated field that shows if one date value is greater than another:

```
=(IIF(fields!date1.value>fields!date2.value,"late","on time")
```

This works fine when there is a value in `fields!date2`.

However, if `fields!date2.value` is blank, the expression returns "on time". I don't want it to do this, as `date1` may be 1/4/15 - if `date2` is blank, that mean's it's overdue and I therefore want the calculated field to say "late".

Therefore I want the expression to say "late" if `fields!date1.value` is < today's date (basically, if it's blank and `fields!date1.value` is before today's date, then it means it's overdue).

Can anyone advise on how to amend the expression to accommodate this?

Comment: Just to clarify, `date1` is the due date and cannot be null, `date2` is the achievement date and can be null, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on "on time"

Here is what's define "on time" (everything else will be considered as "late"):

- `Date2` is not null and `Date1` >= `Date2`
- `Date2` is null and `Date1` >= today

Let's convert it into expressions:

- `Not(Fields!date1.Value Is Nothing) And (Fields!date1.Value >= Fields!date2.Value`
- `Fields!date2.Value Is Nothing And Fields!date1.Value >= Today()`

Here is the full expression:

```
=Iif((Not(Fields!date2.Value Is Nothing) And (Fields!date1.Value >= Fields!date2.Value) Or (Fields!date2.Value Is Nothing And Fields!date1.Value >= Today())), "on time", "late")
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to get back: this helped and I can now do what I need: I have also learnt something. Many thanks.